# Run script when checkbox is un-checked and re-checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Currently I have a script that inputs the current date and time and the users email in two adjacent columns when they check a checkbox in Google Sheets. I'd like to be able to add additional emails if the checkbox is un-checked and re-checked, however I'm lost and not sure which direction to go for completing this. This is what my sheet currently looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmXzq.png). Ideally I want nothing to happen when the box is unchecked, and when it is rechecked I want the users email added to the next email column. All users are in the same Google Workspace domain so hopefully recording emails shouldn't be an issue. My initial thought is that I'll have to add an additional checkbox to complete this, but I wanted to see if there was another way. How would I do this?

This is what my code looks like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  const range = e.range;
  range.setNote(email + new Date());
    if(sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE") {
      e.range.offset(0,1,1,2).setValues([[new Date(),email]]);
    }
    else if(sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "FALSE") {
      e.range.offset(0,1,1,3).setValues([[email]]);
    }
  }
```

Thanks for any suggestions or help

Comment: Please explain actions when unChecked and reChecked in greater detail.  And note that you won't always be able to get users email so what you wish to do in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a checkbox and when a user unchecks and then checks the checkbox, you would want to add additional operations. If my understanding of the question is accurate, then you can quickly reach your goal by using simple boolean logic.

You only have to add a boolean flag that fires when the user unchecks the checkbox, let's call that `uncheck`. Then you could add a boolean flag called `recheck` that activates when the checkbox is activated, but only if it was previously deactivated. Finally, you could use both booleans to introduce your additional operations. See the example below and let me know if you need further explanations.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var uncheck = false;
  var recheck = false;
  const range = e.range;
  range.setNote(email + new Date());

  if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value ==
    "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).setValues([
      [new Date(), email]
    ]);
    if (uncheck == true) {
      recheck = true;
    }
  } else if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e
    .value == "FALSE") {
    uncheck = true;
    e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 3).setValues([
      [email]
    ]);
  }

  if (uncheck && recheck) {
    // Additional operations
  }
}
```

Comment: The if statements have two expressions (there is a comma separating them)... the first one is ignored. The second setValues, as the corresponding range has one row and three columns, should have three values but it only have one.

Comment: Instead of `FALSE`, use `false` or `"FALSE"`. Instead of `TRUE` use `true` or `"TRUE"`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Rubén, I'll update my answer to lowercase the boolean primitives. I will keep the rest intact, because the user provided it as is and it is outside of the question scope, but you are right.